# how to return 2 values from a list?

Tags: php, javascript

I have the following javascript functions:

```
// JavaScript Document

function showList() {
   sList = window.open("CLASS_LIST.PHP", "list", "width=421,height=600");
}
function remLink() {
   if (window.sList && window.sList.open && !window.sList.closed)
      window.sList.opener = null;
}

function pick(symbol) {
   if (window.opener && !window.opener.closed)
      window.opener.document.student.admission_class.value = symbol;
   window.close();
}
```

in the form tag I called this function:

```
<input name="admission_class" type="text" />
<INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="List" onClick="showList()">
```

It open the list in a new window and on selection return the class_id, but I want to return the class_name also which is from the same table.

My requirement to open a list in a new window and on selection return the class_id and class_name to my form.

Comment: onClick should be written: `onclick`

Answer (score 1):

You can return an Array like this:

```
return Array('class_id', 'class_name');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `pick()` function appears to be directly setting the value of the `admission_class` field on the parent window. Presumably this is the `class_id` that you mention is already being returned. If you want to also return `class_name` then the simplest thing is to create a second input field on the parent screen and set it in the same way:

```
<!-- add to your form: -->
<input name="admission_class_name" type="text" />

<script>
// update your pick function:
function pick(symbol, clickedanchor) {
   if (window.opener && !window.opener.closed) {
      window.opener.document.student.admission_class.value = symbol;
      window.opener.document.student.admission_class_name.value =
                                                       clickedanchor.innerHTML;
   }
   window.close();
}

</script>
```

And in your PHP:

```
echo '<tr><td><a href="javascript:pick('.$get_row['class_id'].', this)">' .$get_row['class_name'].'</a></‌​td></tr>';
```

Note: this whole setup is kind of yucky, but something like what I showed above is a minimal change to do what you are asking.

Comment: in called list script CLASS_LIST.PHP I called the pick as         echo '<tr><td><a href="javascript:pick('.$get_row['class_id'].')">'.$get_row['class_name'].'</a></td></tr>'; now how to call the pick() regarding you above admission_class_name